# What does $ stand for?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can somebody explain me what the $ stands for in the following lines, please ? And what are the 'rules' to use it ?

```
$ python python/my_test_imagenet.py 

$ ipython python/my_test_imagenet.py
```

Comment: It's supposed to be your shell prompt. No need to type it in.

Comment: It probably just indicates a shell prompt. Don't worry about it.

Comment: it __is__ figuring your shell prompt (whatever your own shell prompt looks like).

Comment: Traditionally, a shell prompt either ends with $, % or #. If it ends with $, this indicates a shell that's compatible with the Bourne shell (such as a POSIX shell, or a Korn shell, or Bash). If it ends with %, this indicates a C shell (csh or tcsh). If it ends with #, this indicates that the shell is running as the system's superuser account (root), and that you should be extra careful.

Comment: Oh and yes: this has nothing to do with Python - you'll see this in all linux/unix/bsd etc tutorials etc.

Comment: thanks ! so the command prompt in windows is a shell prompt, right ?

Comment: and what's the diffenrence btw shell prompt/prompt/environment/emulator ?

Comment: @Janjouneh: The environment can mean different things to different people, you need to be specific about the context where you have seen the term.  An emulator emulates a terminal type.  For others see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014344/terminal-or-console-or-shell-or-command-prompt/21016640#21016640

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` is the convention for a shell prompt *running under a normal user*.  So it is not to be specifically typed.

If the command is to be run under a userid of 0, usually `root`, then the prompt convention is `#`.

Note that c-shell (`csh` and `tcsh`) use `%` regardless of the userid.

Comment: Until now I have seen the $ just in comments/questions while trying to debug my programm. So where am I supposed to use it mylsef ? While coding ? Writting a prompt command ?

Comment: It is documentary only, you do not type it in.  You don't use it yourself unless you are writing documentation, and then it should be in a different font.  It indicates that the text which *follows* is to be typed into the command-line.  It's an author's device, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

From [Command_prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt):

> On many Unix and derivative systems, the prompt commonly ends in `$` or `%` if the user is a normal user, but in `#` if the user is a superuser ("root" in Unix terminology).

So from your example:

```
$ python python/my_test_imagenet.py
```

Because of the `$` it can be understood as run `python python/my_test_imagenet.py` as a normal user (not root)

Answer (score -1):

It is part of the terminal/shell prompt command. Does not affect the lines.